# Transparent background with pgfgantt figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I searched the documentation and didn't find anything related, but is it possible to have a transparent background for a `pgfgantt` object?

I'd like to put the figure into a presentation, and the text on the left is on a transparent background, but everything else in the chart has a white background. I'd like to have the `\ganttbar` be opaque white, but that's it.

MWE below the picture
[image: gantt image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=0.5in]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

    \begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,%hgrid,
      x unit=7mm,
      time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
      compress calendar]{2015-09}{2016-04}
      \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\

      \ganttgroup{Group 1}{2015-09}{2016-04}\\
      \ganttbar{Task 1}{2015-09}{2015-11}\\
      \ganttbar[name=task2]{Task 2}{2015-10}{2015-12}\\
      \ganttbar{Task 3}{2015-12}{2016-04}\\

      \ganttgroup{Group 2}{2015-11}{2016-03} \\
      \ganttbar{Task 4}{2015-11}{2015-12}\\
      \ganttbar[name=task4]{Task 5}{2016-01}{2016-03}\\

      \ganttlink{task2}{task4}

    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `canvas` style to use some filling opacity using something like:

```
canvas/.append style={fill opacity=0.2}
```

to have a semi-translucent background (0 will be completely translucent and 1 will be completely opaque). A similar addition can also be applied to the other elements, if required. A complete example in which I made completely translucent some of the elements involved and used `fill opcity=0.5` for the groups so they are filled by semi-translucent:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{papiro}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,%hgrid,
      x unit=7mm,
      time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
      compress calendar,
      canvas/.append style={fill opacity=0},
      bar/.append style={fill opacity=0},
      group/.append style={fill opacity=0.5},
      milestone/.append style={fill opacity=0},
      title/.append style={fill opacity=0},
      ]{2015-09}{2016-04}
      \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\

      \ganttgroup{Group 1}{2015-09}{2016-04}\\
      \ganttbar{Task 1}{2015-09}{2015-11}\\
      \ganttbar[name=task2]{Task 2}{2015-10}{2015-12}\\
      \ganttbar{Task 3}{2015-12}{2016-04}\\

      \ganttgroup{Group 2}{2015-11}{2016-03} \\
      \ganttbar{Task 4}{2015-11}{2015-12}\\
      \ganttbar[name=task4]{Task 5}{2016-01}{2016-03}\\

      \ganttlink{task2}{task4}

    \end{ganttchart}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Another option, specially of you want completely translucent elements is to use `fill=none`, as in

```
 canvas/.append style={fill=none}
```

Comment: Setting `canvas/.append style={fill opacity=0}` was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @chasely You're welcome! I added another option (`fill=none`) at the bottom of my answer; it might be of interest for you.